# error while applying SUPEE-9767

Tags: magento1.9.3.1, supee-9767

I'm on a CE 1.9.3.1, already patched with SUPEE-9652.
Trying to apply SUPEE-9767 on localhost (Wamp) with GIT. But I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 141 with fuzz 1.
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1285 (offset -2 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
can't find file to patch at input line 1020
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/Maged/Connect.php downloader/Maged/Connect.php
|index 5c4faf6..1535a4a 100644
|--- downloader/Maged/Connect.php
|+++ downloader/Maged/Connect.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 1052
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/Maged/Controller.php downloader/Maged/Controller.php
|index 84a0184..bef60c0 100644
|--- downloader/Maged/Controller.php
|+++ downloader/Maged/Controller.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 1115
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
|index 8fb1a03..1cc5e56 100644
|--- downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
|+++ downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please apply the patch file by file. 
https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-9767-without-ssh/

download respective zip file of your magento version